# DRF responses me by 403 error when I try to request as a client [Client Credential grant]

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

In `settings.py` file I have written this settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

When I call any API with a token from a `password grant` application, then It's working fine, but when I try to call the same APIs with a token from a `client credential grant` application, it doesn't work and it responses with 403 error:

```
{ "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action." }.
```

Is it because of default permission? I don't know what permission do I have to use instead!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally solved! The problem was the `permission` I was using. In fact, the `IsAuthenticated` permission checks `request.user` which is `None` when you are using `client credentials` grant. Since there's no `permission` for supporting `clien credentials` grant in DRF, you must use your own [DRF custom permission](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions). This is what I needed and used:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission
class IsAuthenticatedOrClientCredentialPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.auth is None:
            return False
        grant_type = request.auth.application.get_authorization_grant_type_display()
        if request.user is None:
            if grant_type == 'Client credentials':
                request.user = request.auth.application.user  # <-- this is because I needed to get the user either the grant is 'password' or 'client credentials'
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
```

But you may want to have a permission just for checking if the grant type is `client credentials` and give the permission, if so, this is what you need:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission
class ClientCredentialPermission(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.auth is None:
            return False
        grant_type = request.auth.application.get_authorization_grant_type_display()
        if request.user is None and grant_type == 'Client credentials':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

**Note:** if you want to use the second custom permission, be aware that the `request.user` is `None` and you can get the owner of the client (that is sending request to you) via `request.auth.application.user`.

#### Using (custom) permissions:

You can use your custom permission by adding them to proper views. (Just like using any DRF permissions under `rest_framework.permissions`)

**class-based views:**

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [ClientCredentialPermission]  # <-- Add your permissions to this list

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

**function-based views:**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([ClientCredentialPermission])  # <-- Add your permissions to this list
def example_view(request, format=None):
    content = {
        'status': 'request was permitted'
    }
    return Response(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The issue in my case was the @authentication_classes that was originally enabled for when I was using credentials directly (not token). I removed them (see them below commented out). Idea came after reading the first answer here.

This works for me as I only want token base access, and so I don't need the other authentication classes. This is how my view decoration looks like:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
#@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def apilink(request, format=None):
      .....
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to enable tokenAuthentication and run migration to apply changes in auth table DB

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',  # <-- And here
    ],
}

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
]
```

Here is the perfect blog for your usecase.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html#implementing-the-token-authentication

Comment: There's no problem with the token. I can get an access_token by client_id and client_secret of a client credential type application. The problem is that when I try to use this token, I'm getting 403 response!